# rake aborted after tests run & (intentionally) fail, before error messages are printed

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, rake

I am running through the [TestFirst](http://testfirst.org/learn_ruby) tutorial and can't get past the first challenge due to some troubles with Rake (and rspec in general).

The tests I am trying to run:

```
require 'hello'

describe "the hello function" do
  it "says hello" do
    hello.should == "Hello!"
  end
end

describe "the greet function" do
  it "says hello to someone" do
    greet("Alice").should == "Hello, Alice!"
  end

  it "says hello to someone else" do
    greet("Bob").should == "Hello, Bob!"
  end
end
```

I've only gotten so far as to create the hello.rb file (according to the tutorial) and adding

```
def hello
end
```

For the record, before I created the file, I got the long output saying that the require "hello" wasn't working, as expected, and upon creating the file that went away. So that all worked fine.

When I run the rake command, my output is (the bolded part is my main concern):

> wendy@wendy-EL1352:~/the_odin_project/learn_ruby/00_hello$ rake
>   (in /home/wendy/the_odin_project/learn_ruby)
>
> the hello function
>    says hello (FAILED - 1)
>
> Failures:
>
> 1) the hello function says hello
>       Failure/Error: hello.should == "Hello!"
>         expected: "Hello!"
>              got: nil (using ==)
>       # ./00_hello/hello_spec.rb:120:in `block (2 levels) in '
>
> Deprecation Warnings:
>
> Using `should` from rspec-expectations' old `:should` syntax without explicitly enabling >the syntax is deprecated. Use the new `:expect` syntax or explicitly enable `:should` >instead. Called from /home/wendy/the_odin_project/learn_ruby/00_hello/hello_spec.rb:120:in >`block (2 levels) in '.
>
> If you need more of the backtrace for any of these deprecations to
>   identify where to make the necessary changes, you can configure
>   `config.raise_errors_for_deprecations!`, and it will turn the
>   deprecation warnings into errors, giving you the full backtrace.
>
> 1 deprecation warning total
>
> Finished in 0.00334 seconds (files took 0.14558 seconds to load)
>   1 example, 1 failure
>
> Failed examples:
>
> rspec ./00_hello/hello_spec.rb:119 # the hello function says hello
>   **rake aborted!
>   /home/wendy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby -S rspec /home/wendy/the_odin_project/learn_ruby/00_hello/hello_spec.rb -I/home/wendy/the_odin_project/learn_ruby/00_hello -I/home/wendy/the_odin_project/learn_ruby/00_hello/solution -f documentation -r ./rspec_config failed
>   /home/wendy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb:156:in `run_task'
>   /home/wendy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb:124:in`block (2 levels) in initialize'
>   /home/wendy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb:122:in `block in initialize'
>   Tasks: TOP => default => spec
>   (See full trace by running task with --trace)**

I'm not hugely concerned with the deprecation warning (I've looked through enough to be reasonably certain these aren't related). Although if you think that's the cause I'll bow my head in shame. I do need to figure out how to either rewrite the specs or change the config settings, but I have faith that I can do that myself. My real concern here is that Rake has access to the tests and can run them, but aborts before showing the error messages.

If I run rspec hello_spec.rb the output is here:

> wendy@wendy-EL1352:~/the_odin_project/learn_ruby/00_hello$ rspec hello_spec.rb
>   /home/wendy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- hello (LoadError)
>       from /home/wendy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>       from /home/wendy/the_odin_project/learn_ruby/00_hello/hello_spec.rb:116:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /home/wendy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in`load'
>       from /home/wendy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `block in load_spec_files'
>       from /home/wendy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in`each'
>       from /home/wendy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `load_spec_files'
>       from /home/wendy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in`setup'
>       from /home/wendy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
>       from /home/wendy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in`run'
>       from /home/wendy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
>       from /home/wendy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/exe/rspec:4:in`'
>       from /home/wendy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
>       from /home/wendy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/bin/rspec:23:in`'

So I'm kind of wondering why running rake has no problem linking the required hello.rb file but the rspec command doesn't. I just want to get these tests to run (and fail) properly so I can get on with the task.

The rakefile:

```
# This Rakefile has all the right settings to run the tests inside each lab
gem 'rspec', '~>2'
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

task :default => :spec

desc "run tests for this lab"
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new do |task|
  lab = Rake.application.original_dir
  task.pattern = "#{lab}/*_spec.rb"
  task.rspec_opts = [ "-I#{lab}", "-I#{lab}/solution", '-f documentation', '-r ./rspec_config']
  task.verbose = false
end
```

Adding gem 'ruby gems' does nothing but add more confusion to the outputs.

I have initialized rspec with rspec --init in previous attempts at this, both in the 00_hello directory as well as in the learn_ruby directory. In this case, I run into exactly the same error messages.

I've been going at learning Ruby and Rails for the past few months. Once or twice I've almost asked a question here, but I've ended up finding my answer halfway through drafting it. I am not having that kind of luck this time. I am truly stumped. Please help.

Thank you.

**Edit with more info on rspec --init and use of 'spec_helper'**

in the 00_hello folder, rspec --init and then including the spec_helper in the hello_spec.rb (as shown above - I included require 'spec_helper' below the require 'hello') produces the following error when run with the rake command:

> wendy@wendy-EL1352:~/the_odin_project/learn_ruby/00_hello$ rake (in
>   /home/wendy/the_odin_project/learn_ruby)
>   /home/wendy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require': cannot load such file -- spec_helper (LoadError)

In the learn_ruby directory, I get the same output as above, where the tests run well enough to fail, but then I see rake abort! before the errors are listed and the same error as before:

> the hello function   says hello (FAILED - 1)
>
> Failures:
>
> 1) the hello function says hello
>        Failure/Error: hello.should == "Hello!"
>        NameError:
>          undefined local variable or method `hello' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::TheHelloFunction:0x00000002989278>
>        # ./00_hello/hello_spec.rb:122:in`block (2 levels) in '
>
> Finished in 0.00094 seconds (files took 0.16985 seconds to load) 1
>   example, 1 failure
>
> Failed examples:
>
> rspec ./00_hello/hello_spec.rb:121 # the hello function says hello
>   rake aborted! /home/wendy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby -S
>   rspec /home/wendy/the_odin_project/learn_ruby/00_hello/hello_spec.rb
>   -I/home/wendy/the_odin_project/learn_ruby/00_hello -I/home/wendy/the_odin_project/learn_ruby/00_hello/solution -f documentation -r ./rspec_config failed

(the reason the test failure is different is because I've gone back to just having the hello.rb file created without inserting the class name into the file - the tests are half running, but the rake aborted! won't go away)

This guy:

> -I/home/wendy/the_odin_project/learn_ruby/00_hello/solution -f documentation -r ./rspec_config failed

can be found in the Rakefile:

```
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new do |task|
  lab = Rake.application.original_dir
  task.pattern = "#{lab}/*_spec.rb"
  **task.rspec_opts = [ "-I#{lab}", "-I#{lab}/solution", '-f documentation', '-r ./rspec_config']**
  task.verbose = false
end
```

But I do not have enough understanding of Rake to even parse apart Google search results for problems with that line, or find what search terms to use to find relevant information. :/

Comment: Is that the totality of the spec? there's not `require "spec_helper"` line ? (Note: I'm not willing to download the entire zipped tutorial to check what it should be... this is based on my knowledge of the usual kind of specs).

Comment: There is no spec_helper file in the initial download. I'll update the original question with more details on that. Attempting to rspec --init and then include 'spec_helper' causes a different error. I'll go through various attempts and include the outputs in my OP.